# Spacing between sections using titlesec

Tags: titlesec

In my LyX preamble (though, I don't think that this is related to LyX) I have this:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\scshape}
{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[. \ ]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont}
{\thesubparagraph}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{10pt}{8pt}{0pt}
```

Following usual text block, the paragraph environment puts 10pt space as expected; however, following a **subparagraph**, it does not.

What am I missing?

[image]

EDIT: Exported LyX code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage{libertine-type1}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{beramono}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=36pc,paperheight=54pc]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=6pc,bmargin=9pc,lmargin=6pc,rmargin=6pc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usepackage[tracking=false]{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\normalfont\color{gray}}
{\normalsize\MakeUppercase{\textls[400]{\chaptertitlename}} \textls[400]{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}}
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pt}%
\LARGE\scshape\color{darkgray}}



\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\scshape}
{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[. \ ]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}


\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont}
{\thesubparagraph}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{10pt}{10pt}{4pt}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\cdot\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Titlesec Problem}

\maketitle

\chapter{Titlesec Spacing}


\paragraph*{Philosophy}

Game before slam. Always. Until it is settled in which strain we expect
to play, control-bidding does not apply.


\paragraph*{Paragraph}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rebum laudem fabulas has ne. An vix oratio
adipisci nominati. Mea et tale quaeque appareat, te nam viris congue,
ex nonumes reformidans per. Ea mei graeco electram, in vix sumo liber
graecis. Aliquip intellegat an pri, no usu tritani legendos.


\paragraph*{Another Paragraph}

Tation mollis prodesset has at. Iudico patrioque mei no, sed at solum
labore impetus. Mel virtute singulis ea, nec ut utinam iuvaret ancillae,
vix consetetur referrentur ei. Ut mei legere omittam imperdiet, quod
simul cum eu, vix justo blandit ut.

Ei sit modus aperiam persequeris, ei viris veritus cum. Cibo nominati
ne quo. Viris integre ut per. Ne assentior vituperatoribus usu. Eam
nullam numquam te.


\subparagraph*{(1) Subparagraph}


\subparagraph*{(2) Another subparagraph}


\paragraph*{Paragraph}

Dicit dolores torquatos eos in. Vel labitur abhorreant ne. Ei vis
harum dolore, eam ea altera nusquam mediocritatem. Nostrud senserit
voluptatum cum ea, vix ei expetendis scriptorem.

Ea viderer oblique neglegentur nec. Sea saepe laboramus honestatis
ex, tamquam contentiones eu qui. Augue electram periculis eu cum,
in pri nobis verterem. Mel te falli dictas. Et splendide quaerendum
vel, aeque ludus labores ne quo, option intellegat duo ei. Posse inciderint
nam te.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are supposed to have `subparagraph` in `runin` fromat isn't it? Add that option like `\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expanding @user11232 answer: the issue is solved specifying the optional `runin` parameter in the formatting part of the `subparagraph` ie:

```
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont}
{\thesubparagraph}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{10pt}{10pt}{4pt}
```

This ensure proper formatting and spacing for the run-in titles such as these `subparagraph`. The default options spaces differently since is usually set to `block` which should be used for centered titles

[image]